# return loops in java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

This is a method for part of a larger class that creates a backpack object based on different values entered by the user. This is the one that will determine what color the user wants. The problem is that I keep getting an error saying that it must return a string when I want it to only do that if the user inputs a valid answer. If they don't, it's supposed to loop back to the start of the method.

```
public String pickc(){
    String cchoice = "blank";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (cchoice=="blank"){
    System.out.println("Please choose a color.");

    System.out.println("You can have red, blue, yellow, green, purple, or orange");
    cchoice = input.nextLine();
    if(cchoice == "red" || cchoice == "blue" || cchoice == "yellow" || cchoice == "green" || cchoice == "purple" || cchoice == "orange"){
        return cchoice;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid color");
        cchoice = "blank";
        pickc();
    }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to  add "return  pickc(); " at end of else statement to make it recursive.

Comment: Among other things, you may wish to look at your String comparisons.

Comment: I tried the return pickc() in the else. It didn't work. KevinO can you be more specific regarding the string comparisons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to both loop until they choose a valid color, (That's what your while loop is doing, and this is how I'd do it), and you're trying to recursivly call your function again when they enter an invalid color. Either of these could work, but you should pick one, and use that to solve this problem.
In general, you would get that error when the compiler isn't sure that the program will return a string. Like, if you have a return statement inside your while loop, the compiler doesn't know for sure that the while loop will actually run, because sometimes while-loops' condition statement is false, and the whole while loop is skipped.
You know that the program shouldn't ever go past the while loop, so you can just put
    `return ""`
 at the bottom, or you could throw an error at that point.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I have another question but I'll ask it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operand compares the references not the strings. Instead, use `firstString.equals(secondString)`

Comment: Although this is true, it doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: But what I see is that since there is no correct comparaison there will not be a *valid answer*

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that calling `pickc()` again does not loop back to the start as you expect, but instead calls the function again from the current context. When your newly called `pickc` then returns, the calling method continues in it's execution. In case of `pickc` that means that you hit the end of the method without having returned anything, which is why the compiler complains. The simplest solution would be to replace `pickc();` at the end of your method with `return pickc();` so that you pass the value returned from the nested function call. However, it would be advisable to restructure your logic so you don't have to resort to use recursion, since that can lead to stack overflow errors and the like.

Comment: I tried using return pickc() but i'm still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot see a definite returning of a String. It is possible that the else branch will be taken and no String will be returned.

Why are you using recursion? Try using a while loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

> The Simple method to do that you declare a variable of boolean type and wrap the code in loop, and if the user select right color change the value of the boolean variable to false, then break the loop and in the end of this function return cchoice variable.

```
public String pickc()
{
boolean check = true;
String cchoice = "blank";
while(check== true)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose a color.");
    System.out.println("You can have red, blue, yellow, green, purple, or orange");
    cchoice = input.nextLine();
   if(cchoice == "red" || cchoice == "blue" || cchoice == "yellow" || cchoice == "green" || cchoice == "purple" || cchoice == "orange"){
    check = false;
     break;
   }
   else
   {
      System.out.println("Enter a valid color");
      cchoice = "";
      pickc();
   }   
 }
return cchoice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by @David the compiler doesnot know that the method will actually `return String`, it can choose `else` condition infinitely as never `return String` . However you dont need `recursive` to get what you want. 
Run the `while` loop till the `cchoice == "blank"` and `return` if the color is chosen. 
See below for reference :
Note : you can also do `equalsIgnoreCase` if you are not sure about the `case` of the input.

```
public String pickc(){
    String cchoice = "blank";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (cchoice.equals("blank")){
    System.out.println("Please choose a color.");
    System.out.println("You can have red, blue, yellow, green, purple, or orange");
    cchoice = input.nextLine();
       if(!cchoice.equals("red") && !cchoice.equals("blue") && !cchoice.equals("yellow") && !cchoice.equals("green") && !cchoice.equals("purple") && !cchoice.equals("orange")){
             cchoice = "blank";
        } 
    }
    return cchoice;
}
```